# How to remove entire panel if one value in panel is missing using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, multi-index, panel-data

I have a panel data set that generally looks like this (it is much larger).

```
df['fips'] = ['01001', '01001', '01001', '01003', '01003', '01003', '01005', '01005', '01005']

df['year'] = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003]

df['var1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

df['var2'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(df)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    fips  year  var1  var2
0  01001  2001     1   1.0
1  01001  2002     2   2.0
2  01001  2003     3   3.0
3  01003  2001     4   4.0
4  01003  2002     5   NaN
5  01003  2003     6   6.0
6  01005  2001     7   7.0
7  01005  2002     8   8.0
8  01005  2003     9   9.0
```

What I am hoping to do is remove the entire 'fips' panel that contains a nan value so it would look like this:

```
    fips  year  var1  var2
0  01001  2001     1   1.0
1  01001  2002     2   2.0
2  01001  2003     3   3.0
3  01005  2001     7   7.0
4  01005  2002     8   8.0
5  01005  2003     9   9.0
```

I have tried creating a Multi-Index on 'fips' and 'year' and using dropna, but I am only able to pull out the row that actually contains the na value. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is only var2 which may contain nan's or could var1 also contain nans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to make sure none of the `var2` are null within the group

```
df.groupby('fips').filter(lambda x: ~x['var2'].isnull().any())
```

If you wanted to check both var cols you could try:

```
null_fips = df.loc[df[['var1','var2']].isnull().any(1)]['fips'].unique()
df.loc[~df['fips'].isin(null_fips)]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Not sure I understand what it's doing, but it got the job done.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
def remove_panel(df: pd.DataFrame, pnlColumn: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # remove all references to entries in pnlColumn where at least one is np.nan
    dfo = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns.to_list())
    pnls = list(df[pnlColumn].unique())
    for pnl in pnls:                                                     
        if len( np.argwhere(np.isnan(df[df[pnlColumn] == pnl]['var2'].to_numpy())) ) == 0:
            dfo = pd.concat([dfo, df[df[pnlColumn] == pnl]])
    return dfo
```

Given your initial dataframe running

```
remove_panel(df, 'fips')
```

produces:

```
fips    year    var1    var2
0   01001   2001    1   1.0
1   01001   2002    2   2.0
2   01001   2003    3   3.0
6   01005   2001    7   7.0
7   01005   2002    8   8.0
8   01005   2003    9   9.0
```